# Laravel Javascript - Get user role with Javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, axios

I tried to get the user role with Javascript instead of php. with PHP you can do the following:

```
Auth::User()->role()->role_name
```

But how do you do this:

```
                axios.get('./api/users')
                .then(response => {
                    this.users = response.data.users,
                    this.user = this.users[0].role.role_name

                });
```

But that didn't work. How do I have to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript

```
axios.get('/api/user')
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status == 200) {
            this.user = response.data;
            // this.user.role.role_name
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        //
    });
```

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $user = auth()->user()->with('role');
    return response()->json($user, Response::HTTP_OK); // 200 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
}
```

Your web.php

```
Route::get('api/user', 'YourController@index');
```